# Using Here Maps in React Native on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, maps, here-api

I'm working on a proof of concept for work and am trying to recreate a portion of our current iOS app in react-native.  I've been doing a lot of research and have only found ways to use Google Maps in react-native for iOS. My company uses Here maps so I'm wondering if anyone has found a way to implement them in React Native?

Or at least know why they can't currently be implemented.

Comment: Misread this the first time around. The only Here maps module I've found is [react-native-heremaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-heremaps) which only works on Android. Unless the company or someone else writes a module for iOS, you will need to write a [native bridge](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) yourself to expose the [Here maps iOS SDK](https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks) in React Native.

Answer (score 1):

HERE maps does not have any react native bindings. You will need to write a react binding to the HERE maps APIs yourself.